# Which class does this NP problem belong to?

Tags: complexity

Suppose $n$ inputs ($x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_n$) can take on any of $m$ values, say $\{ k_1, k_2, k_3, \cdots, k_m \}$, and that there is a cost function $y = f(x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_n)$. For instance, for $n = 3$ ($x_1, x_2, x_3$) and $m = 2$ ($\{ k_1, k_2 \}$) we have a total of $8$ possible triplets $S = \{ (k_1k_1k_1), (k_1k_1k_2), (k_1k_2k_1), (k_1k_2k_2), (k_2k_1k_1), (k_2k_1k_2), (k_2k_2k_1), (k_2k_2k_2) \}$. The objective is to find the triplet that minimizes $y$ without enumerating all possibilities.

I tried to relate this NP problem to various problems in combinatorial optimization (e.g., TSP, 0/1 Knapsack, Assignment Problem, etc.), but found none that could barely resemble it.

Which class does this NP problem belong to?

EDIT: The problem I have at hand is a regression problem where each of $n$ inputs, $x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_n$, needs to undergo a variable transformation using one of $q$ basis functions from a set of available functions $F = \{ f_1, f_2, f_3, \cdots, f_q \}$. The cost function is the Mean Square Error (MSE) defined as $MSE = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{k=1}^p (y_k - \hat{y}_k)^2$, where $p$ is the number of samples and for each $k$, $y_k$ is an experimental value and $\hat{y}_k$ is the predicted value computed by some method (e.g., as from a Gaussian Process Regression) using the transformations ($f_j(x_i)$) as input variables. This method must be also selected from a set $M = \{ M_1, M_2, M_3, \cdots, M_m \}$ of widely different available methods. The objective is to decide which function transforms each one of the $n$ inputs and which method to use such that $MSE$ is minimum. There are no constraints whatsoever.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's a typical combinatorial problem you would solve through something like branch-and-bound. To say more about what existing problem it could be mapped to, you need to say more about how your function $f(x)$ looks like.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth This is exactly where the problem gets weird. The cost function $f(g_i(x))$ depends on the choice of $g_i(x)$, where $i \in \{1,2,3,\cdots,q\}$ is one of the inputs. Hence, I believe there is no way to define some structure out of $f(x)$. Even though we could fix $g(x)$, it would still be computed by some method, i.e., there would be no clear cut closed form for it.

Comment: Nah, surely there is a way to do exactly what you want to do using binary (zero/one)variables, and I'm certain that there is a standard way to formulate what you want to do. I just don't know the field well enough to say what it is. You might be better off explaining in your question how precisely the cost function is defined, and let people go to town with providing suggestions.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth. I think now I went more to the point..